# NSFileManager how to return folder name of file path

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsfilemanager

I have this path:

```
/Users/mac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/5C6B84DE-2F18-48A8-AC4D-5C4973F19050/tmp/Root/Folder 1/test.pdf
```

I want to extract `/Users/mac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/5C6B84DE-2F18-48A8-AC4D-5C4973F19050/tmp/Root/Folder 1/` from this path.

Can I use `NSFileManager` for getting directory path that contains test.pdf file or do I need parse it by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using `stringByDeletingLastPathComponent` of [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) class:

```
NSString *path = @"/Users/mac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/5C6B84DE-2F18-48A8-AC4D-5C4973F19050/tmp/Root/Folder 1/test.pdf";

NSString *folder = [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

**[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByDeletingLastPathComponent) :**

> **stringByDeletingLastPathComponent**
>
> Returns a new string made by deleting the last path component from the
>   receiver, along with any final path separator.
>
> `- (NSString *)stringByDeletingLastPathComponent`
>
> **Return Value**
>
> A new string made by deleting the last path component from the
>   receiver, along with any final path separator. If the receiver
>   represents the root path it is returned unaltered. Discussion
>
> Note that this method only works with file paths (not, for example,
>   string representations of URLs).

[image: stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stringByDeletingLastPathComponent`

```
 NSString *path=@"";
   NSString *path1= [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want file path without file name, let use like below

```
NSString * filePath = [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use NSString's class method `stringByDeletingLastPathComponent` for deleting last path component. Hope it will help you.

```
 NSString *path = @"/Users/mac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/5C6B84DE-2F18-48A8-AC4D-5C4973F19050/tmp/Root/Folder 1/test.pdf";

    path = [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];

    NSLog(@"path %@",path);
```